# How to open image-dired in a directory using a key binding?

Tags: spacemacs, image-dired

The binding works, though I'm still required to input the directory `/home/foo/Pictures`.

What do I have to change?

init.el:

```lisp
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "jI"
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (call-interactively #'image-dired "/home/foo/Pictures")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `call-interactively` is:

```
(call-interactively FUNCTION &optional RECORD-FLAG KEYS)
```

In particular, you can't pass arguments to the callee in the way you attempt.

This should work instead:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "jI"
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (image-dired "/home/foo/Pictures")))
```